# Can I display different network devices(router,switch,printers) icon out using SNMP?

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming

I am doing a project whereby I discover the network in the subnet. I use SNMP to retrieve out the devices like switch/router/printers.

My question is: can I use SNMP to query and get different device icons out like router will show routers icon and switch will show switch icon etc on the list view?

Answer (score 1):

You can display any icon you like, but you won't get icons from SNMP.

Comment: because my lecturer told me that he wants to see the router icon if the device type is Router and display Switch icon if the device is switch using snmp..

Comment: So ask him where to get the icon from. If he says 'SNMP' he is wrong. You can't get anything from SNMP except OIDs.

Answer (score 0):

SNMP is a protocol. What you do with SNMP data is entirely up to you, if you want to display a router with a picture of a dog, go ahead.

It all depends on in the structure of the data you receive, and how you wish to display this. It's as easy as:

```
if (device.DeviceType == SNMPDeviceType.Router)
{
    DevicePictureBox.Image = _routerImage;
}
```

Comment: thanks but i need to display the icon for switch, router and printer as well after discovering the network. how to know which device is for which icon to display? and what library did you use for C#?

Comment: I don't get your question. You say: _"I use SNMP to retrieve out the devices like switch/router/printers"_. Then in this data, the device type must be known. Then **you** have to program the logic to translate a device type into an image, this is not SNMP's task. Some actual code you're using could help.

Comment: yes. i retrieve the oid of the router's name which is called "Router" and switch name called "Switch" if one day the router change name to something else i would not know the device type.

Comment: As far as I can find from a quick web search ("snmp find device type") you'll have to manually translate `sysObjectID`s into device types.

Comment: i got the objectID of the router. but how do i know this oid belong to which series of cisco router?

Comment: See http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseMIB.do?local=en&mibName=CISCO-PRODUCTS-MIB for example.

Comment: thks for ur help. but my program is not capable to find out the exact type of the device. The link you gave me must load the MIB but my program could not do that..

Comment: I guess SNMP manager software keeps an up-to-date database that translates sysObjectIDs to information about the device.

Comment: but my program must have the capability to know the device type. if i have the device oid using sysobjectID the results give me a new oid but the oid must have the cisco-mib to know the device. so my question is how to know the device type if i got the oid 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.1.1.3.1.1 ? thanks!

Comment: As far as I understand (I'm far from an SNMP expert), the ID is an identifier that doesn't say anything about the device. It's like a product code, which in this case exists out of a manufacturer part and a model part. If you have an ID like `2.4` it can be a certain switch (model `4`) of manufacturer `2`, but ID `3.4` can be a totally different device, say, a network printer (though numbered model `4` again), made by a different manufacturer (`3`). You said _"my lecturer told me"_ in another comment. Please confirm with your lecturer if these ideas are correct and what you are supposed to do.

Comment: i'm doing my final year project he just ask me to get the device icon out for the any device type searched. he give me one solution is to use iPForwarding and nonIPForwarding this can check the router and switch but computer and printer is also consider nonIPForwarding. so it hard to determine the actual device type unless i know how to get the sysObjectID which is 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.1.1.3.1.1 to know the type of the device.

Comment: Then document what you found and return to him. You can tell him you can detect two device types: routers (`iPForwarding`) and non-routers (`nonIPForwarding`). To me it looks that if you want more detailed information, you'll have to create a database of known devices, their ID and their capabilities. Such databases seem to be freely downloadable if you search the web a bit. I don't know if your lecturer wants you to do so - or if there's another way.